# Optimum set up for large data sets such as mobile service coverage maps

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, geojson, mapquest

When serving up large data sets such as mobile coverage maps (custom tile) mashed up with MapQuest maps and MapQuest POIs, is there any performance benefit to using shapefile vs WMS image PNGs?

Comment: It is using a WMS service https://maps.eng.t-mobile.com/TMo_DataMap/RESTService/getTile?name=TMo_Data&level=4&row=4&col=2&output=gif

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is confused about how web mapping works.

Comment: @joeDev8 use the opensignal developer api http://opensignal.com/network-coverage-maps/t-mobile-coverage-map.php for accessing the data

Comment: edited original question to hopefully meeting the guidelines.

Comment: @joeDev8: You have edited the question so much that now it looks like a totally different question; Are you sure that the question now reflects what you want to know?

Answer (score 2):

The controls on the map appear to be OpenLayers.

Here's how you can find out yourself what kind of data it's using in the client in Chrome or Firefox:

- In Chrome, go to Menu > Tools > Developer Tools and switch to the Network tab.
- In Firefox, go to Menu > Developer > Network
- Refresh the page, pan around the map a few times, see what resources load.

Comment: Hint: it's not sending any vector data to the client at all.